# Java Spring, how to use JSP files hosted at a remote location?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, java-ee-6, remote-access

I have searched on this and found something about using remotely hosted JSPs but it was not specific to Spring and I am not quite sure how to make it work with Spring. I have a situation where I need to give access to a designer who will work on the JSPs but I am not allowed to give access to the rest of the source code for the application. I want him to be able to update the JSPs and see results in real time as the application is running as that will take a lot of pressure off of me having to be the intermediary.. any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to solve the wrong problem.

You should find a way to give the designer isolated access to the JSP directory only, not experiment with wild remoting strategies.

Perhaps set up a script that automatically syncs the designer's JSP directory with the server's whenever changes are made (the actual implementation depends on the platform you are running on).

Comment: I don't think I can do this as he's not running Linux and I don't have much time to devote learning how to make a script like this for Windows, its not my own project (for an employer) so I don't want to have to spend extra time on something like this if possible, I was thinking if I can just have it pull JSPs from a remote location I can just set a location on a different server of FTP that I already have setup, this isn't something I would be doing for production use

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of a back-door approach, but how about just setting up an FTP site with the designer's "home" directory being the directory in which the JSPs have been deployed on your target server.

The designer would need to ftp the updated files into place, but it sounds like at present he's treating you as personal file transport mechanism.

Alternatively, could just just give the compiled class files? If this was Java EE, I would just give the EAR file to the designer, they can then hack the JSPs and redeploy without needing the source. Or edit the deployed app in situ, again no source is needed.

Comment: I thought about doing the FTP, I am not good with that sort of thing though so was hoping to avoid that but may have to.. as far as having the designer deploy anything, thats pretty much out of the question as he's pretty much non-technical and would be too much of a hassle to have him setup an environment where he could run it locally.. :) about the "personal file transport mechanism", currently I have to take the front-end code and break it into JSPs as he is struggling with the modular concept of JSPs so I want him to be able to use them directly to see the output so he can understand

Comment: @Rick Designers often pretend to be dumber than they actually are :-) I usually show them how they can build an app with a single maven command line, and after an initial grumble they usually can work that way

Comment: I see.. but this app is fairly complicated and uses a custom library that sorts through these huge vector files and its just kind of a finnicky thing to get setup on a new machine (having to set the path for these vector files, download them each time there is a change, etc) and I'm not onsite with the designer so not sure I can do it this way

Answer (score 0):

You can use some kind of shared folder service like [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/).

Comment: I am trying that but dropbox is giving me some weird problems where its not synching my files, I may have to just go the setup the ftp route